# how do I search a string for dictionary key and replace it with value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary created by a CSV reader where column A has original names and column B has updated names.

```
dict[key] = {value}
```

I am selecting a value from a database and the objective is to search that string using a key and replace it with value.

It will eventually be updated via UPDATE statement. But it's important that a check is done, if the string doesn't contain any instances of 'key' and has 'value' then it's skipped from the update and not passed to the dict.

What is the best way to search the string? Because it's making duplicate replacements. I want to "match case" throughout the string.

```
name = 'de testing       nl testing       es testing_updated       en testing_updated       it testing       fr testing_updated'
dict["testing"] = {"testing_updated"}
for key,value in dict.items():
    if str(key) not in name and list(value)[0] in name:
        print("{} has already been replaced with {}".format(key,value))
    else:
        name = name.replace(str(key),list(value)[0])
        print(name)
```

Output:

```
de testing_updated       nl testing_updated       es testing_updated_updated       en testing_updated_updated       it testing_updated       fr testing_updated_updated
```

If check is passed and name is updated properly (which it is not) eventually it's passed to a new dictionary and then dictionary is used to compile sql update statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace `"testing"` with `"testing_updated"`, then the resulting string does still contain the string `"testing"`, so your check fails to recognize that it has been updated.

You could use something like `"testing "` and `"testing_updated "` with a trailing whitespace or tab instead, but depending on your actual data, this might not be working in every case.

If I understand you correctly, you have one string that contains updated and not updated elements. In this case, you should probably split the string into the comprising elements first using `str.split`, and than process the elements individually.

Answer (score 0):

Stated, you have a list of replacement instructions in a CSV :

`1 A B
2 B C
....`

If you have a string "AB" and apply search/replace in sequence, your string ends-up being "CC", not "BC".

You have two ways to workaround :

1. do all the searches and then all the replaces. It's quite tricky to implement as you have to cut your input string into pieces
2. modify your instructions to introduce key that are not present in the input string:

   `1 A DISTINGUISH_A
   2 B DISTINGUISH_B
   ....
   ....
   11 DISTINGUISH_A B
   12 DISTINGUISH_B C`

Way 2 is interesting because the main loop does not change : sequence of search and replace. And, preparing modified instructions can be automated too.

Comment: My csv is not replacement like you described. 

It's old_text,new_text pairs. 
like: 

cassette,tape
dog,cat

it wouldn't be:

cassette,tape
tape,duct_tape

Comment: @oj43085 forget line numbers and we are saying the same ; do you get the idea ?